Relation between speed of satellite and radius/orbit
I don't understand how increasing the velocity will lead to increase in the radius at which a satellite orbits. Shouldn't radius decrease i.e satelite should orbit closer to the earth as the velocity increases. You can see that velocity squared is inversely proportional to the radius.


You should specify the way the velocity is increased. The relation you have written (BTW, MathJax formulae are preferable to images) refers to the case where the velocity is increased by keeping the trajectory circular.

Another comment, looking at your notes. Even if it gives the right result, equating the acceleration to the centrifugal force is conceptually wrong. What you have written should be intended as the centripetal force.

A side note: $F_g$ is in fact not the centrifugal force, but the centripetal force. A centrifugal effect would be pushing outwards, away from the circle, not inwards.

Kindly note that when you only post photographs of formulas, people with visual disabilities who rely on screen readers are excluded from being able to read your content.  Please enter all formulas as text so all people can participate.  Thanks.  For details, please read: https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation

If you fire a short rocket burst to increase your speed, you will start moving farther from the planet, and, as you move farther away, you will slow down. When you get to the opposite side of the orbit, you will be at maximum distance and slowest speed. Then you will speed up as you fall back towards the earth (still in orbit, just getting closer), until you end up back where you were when you fired your burst. At that point you will be going just as fast as you were right after firing your rocket, and you can just stay in that orbit, going fast as you are nearest the planet and slow when you are farther away.
If you want to be in a circular orbit, you have to fire your rocket when you are at the farthest point. The reason your orbit isn't circular is that, when you're at the farthest point, you are going below orbital velocity for a circular orbit of that distance. So you fire your rocket a bit to get up to the speed you need. That is slower than you were moving when you were in the lower circular orbit, but faster than you were at the farthest point of your elliptical orbit.
